# Does `pip install -U pip -r requirements.txt` upgrade pip before installing the requirements?

Tags: python, pip, python-venv, requirements.txt

It seems to be common practice to set up a Python virtual environment using some variant of the following:

```sh
python -m venv venv && source ./venv/bin/activate
python -m pip install -U pip -r requirements.txt
```

What I hope the above command does is:

1. Upgrade `pip` first
2. Run the installation of the packages in `requirements.txt`

However, what actually seems to happen is:

1. Collects all packages, including newest version of `pip`
2. Installs them all together

   - The original/outdated version of `pip` is what actually runs the installs
   - And the new version of `pip` is *not* used until after this command

---

**Question(s)**

1. Is it possible to have pip upgrade itself and then install a requirements file, in one command?

   - Would this infer any particular benefits?
2. Should I switch to the following?

```sh
python -m venv venv && source ./venv/bin/activate
python -m pip install -U pip
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

3. What is the optimal method to install requirements files?

   - I see people sometimes installing/upgrading `wheel` and `setuptools` as well

Comment: I had the same question with weels since it was breaking my bcrypt package installation. Doing the weels installation as a separate command first and then my requirements, worked well.

Comment: I think you're confusing three things: `one command`, `one process` and `a single line`. You could write a single line with two commands which does what you want, but it will never be a single process, since a running command is by definition using a binary, and therefore the binary can't change *and* in the same process execution, use this changed new binary version to perform another step. This would be, by definition (although you may appreciate it from outside as one step), two processes being performed one after another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers to your questions are:

1. No. `pip` doesn't currently treat itself as a special dependency, so it doesn't know to install then execute itself, which is what it would need to do to overcome the problems you observed.
2. Updating `pip` in a separate step is indeed the recommended way to proceed.

You may from time to time see `pip` issue a message advising that a newer version is available. This happens a lot if you create them from a python with an outdated `pip`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a situation similar to yours, I needed to first upgrade `pip` and then install a bunch of libraries in a lab that had 20 PCs. What I did was writing all the librarie's name in a `requirements.txt` file, then create a `.bat` file with two commands:

```
`python -m pip install --upgrade pip`
`pip install -r requirements.txt`
```

The first command for upgrading `pip` and the second one for installing all the libraries listed in the `requirements.txt` file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what `pip install -h` says about `-U`:

```
  -U, --upgrade   Upgrade all specified packages to the newest available
                  version. The handling of dependencies depends on the
                  upgrade-strategy used.
```

Which I think means: *Install the latest version of a library.  If it's already installed but isn't the latest version, then *update* it to the latest version.*